# Using :target and adjacent sibling selectors to make a toggle botton

Tags: css, css-selectors

Anyway, I'm trying to create a toggle link, which is basically two buttons on top of each other. One of them would become `display:none` when it is clicked, and vice-versa.

Currently, my CSS is like this

```
#main-nav:target + .page-wrap {
    position:absolute;
    left:-80px;
    #open-menu {
    display: none;
    }
    #close-menu {
    display: block;
    }
}
```

...but the #open-menu and #close-menu display options don't seem to be showing. Any help?

EDIT:
Alright so I need a preprocessor okay ._.

EDIT AGAIN:
Got it working, thanks guys! Just wondering, is there a way for my entire page div (excluding the menu) to slide **out** of the page? Or is it some simple overflow-x:hidden?

Comment: You can't nest rules like that in plain CSS. Are you using some CSS preprocessing?

Comment: I think you need some JavaScript or jQuery to bind an action to the button.  CSS by itself will not do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using a preprocessor and you don't want to, I suspect you can rewrite your CSS like this, assuming your HTML structure actually corresponds to the selectors:

```
#main-nav:target + .page-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    left: -80px;
}

#main-nav:target + .page-wrap #open-menu {
    display: none;
}

#main-nav:target + .page-wrap #close-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Of course, if `#open-menu` and `#close-menu` aren't descendants of `.page-wrap`, then this won't work at all, even if you do use a preprocessor to support writing nested style rules (as a preprocessor can't do something if it cannot already be done with plain CSS).

As mentioned, if these elements aren't related in a way that can be expressed with descendant and sibling combinators, you'll have to make use of JavaScript to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

As a demonstration, I tried the following:

```
<div class="page-wrap">
    <a id="close-menu" href="#open-menu">Close</a> 
    <a id="open-menu" href="#close-menu">Open</a> 
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
.page-wrap #open-menu {
    display: block;
}
.page-wrap #close-menu {
    display: none;
}

.page-wrap #open-menu:target {
    display: block;
}
.page-wrap #open-menu:target + #close-menu {
    display: none;
}

.page-wrap #close-menu:target {
    display: block;
}
.page-wrap #close-menu:target + #open-menu {
    display: none;
}
```

Fiddle Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/5aSdW/
Demo Link: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/5aSdW/show

Every time you click the Open or Close link, the alternate link is displayed.

I am not sure if this is overly useful, but it can be done.